# Spark : skip top rows with spark-excel

Tags: excel, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-excel

I have an excel file with damaged rows on the top (3 first rows) which needs to be skipped, I'm using [spark-excel](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel) library to read the excel file, on their github there no such functionality, so is there a way to achieve this?

This my code:

```
Dataset<Row> ds = session.read().format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
                                .option("location", filePath)
                                .option("sheetName", "Feuil1")
                                .option("useHeader", "true")
                                .option("delimiter", "|")
                                .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
                                .option("inferSchema", "true")
                                .option("addColorColumns", "false")
                                .load(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed with `spark excel 0.9.16`, issue link in [github](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel/issues/65)

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at the source code and there is no option for the same

https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/crealytics/spark/excel/DefaultSource.scala

You should fix your excel file and remove the first 3 rows. Or else you would need to create a patched version of the code to allow you the same. Which would be way more effort then having a correct excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **skipFirstRows** option (I believe it is deprecated after version 0.11)

```
Library Dependency : "com.crealytics" %% "spark-excel" % "0.10.2"
```

Sample Code :

```
val df = sparkSession.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
      .option("location", inputLocation)
      .option("sheetName", "sheet1")
      .option("useHeader", "true")
      .option("skipFirstRows", "2") // Mention the number of top rows to be skipped
      .load(inputLocation)
```

Hope it helps!
Feel free to let me know in comments if you have any doubts/issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`skipFirstRows` was [deprecated](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#0110) in favor of more generic [dataAddress](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel#data-addresses) option. For your specific example, you can skip rows by specifying start range for your data:

```java
Dataset<Row> ds = session.read().format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
                                .option("location", filePath)
                                .option("useHeader", "true")
                                .option("delimiter", "|")
                                .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
                                .option("inferSchema", "true")
                                .option("addColorColumns", "false")
                                .option("dataAddress", "'Feuil1'!A3") // From the docs: Start cell of the data. Reading will return all rows below and all columns to the right
                                .load(filePath);
```